# dimension of Row Vs. Column vector using numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I am learning about arrays in python. I was trying to figure out the dimension of row vector vs. column vector. In the case of a row vector, the dimension comes out to be 1 and the shape a (3,). In the case of a column vector, the dimension comes out to be 2 and the shape (3,1). Why is that? Where did I go wrong?
I wrote the following code:

```
print(b)
print(np.ndim(b))
print(np.shape(b)) 
print(np.size(b))

Output: 
[1 2 3]
1
(3,)
3

c= np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
print(c)
print(np.ndim(c))
print(np.shape(c))
print(np.size(c))

Output: 
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
2
(3, 1)
3
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `numpy` does not have "row vectors" or "column vectors".  It has `arrays`, which may have any (almost) number of dimensions, including 0.  Don't try (too hard) to force the `numpy` into linear algebra terminology.  But look at `np.array([[1,2,3]])`.  It is (1,3) shaped.

Comment: I might add that due to `broadcasting` rules, often a (3,) shaped array is just as useful as a (1,3) shape.  It won't `transpose`, but otherwise it broadcasts with other arrays in the same way.

Comment: Can I say that a= np.array([1, 2, 3]) is a row vector? And 
is b=np.array([1], [2], [3]) a column vector or 3×1 matrix?

Comment: Why do you need to use those names?

Comment: trying to relate it with linear algebra. Is that wrong?

Comment: I could easily relate either  a (3,) or (1,3) array to a "row vector", but I don't know if you understanding of either linear algebra or `numpy` gives your that flexibility.  MATLAB/Octave is closer to text-book linear algebra, since everything is 2d, a matrix.  `numpy` is more general; it has things like transpose and matrix product, and a `linalg` submodule, but it is used for a lot more than text-book LA.

Comment: Could you recommend me some sources to improve my understanding of numpy and how I should view linear algebra in python?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html, especially https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#how-to-convert-a-1d-array-into-a-2d-array-how-to-add-a-new-axis-to-an-array.  I haven't read this, but it looks useful, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/tutorial-svd.html